# Continuously render numpy arrays in loop

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, rendering

I have code that runs in a while loop and returns a new `numpy` array on every iteration. I would like to continuously render that array to an onscreen window.

Based on [Displaying Numpy Matrix as Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541449/displaying-numpy-matrix-as-video), [Is there a way to detach matplotlib plots so that the computation can continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue), [How to update matplotlib's imshow() window interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835302/how-to-update-matplotlibs-imshow-window-interactively), and [real-time plotting in while loop with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1), this is my best attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# plt.ion()
image = np.zeros((800, 800))
im = plt.imshow(image)
while True:
    image += .01
    im.set_data(image)
    plt.pause(0.05)
plt.show()
```

It does not work (for some reason it just renders a purple square that does not change color). I am using ImageMagick on Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple correction:

```
image = np.zeros((800, 800, 3))
```

Now it works.